# Consulta MSSQL no Ubuntu 18.04 LTS parou de funcionar

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, php-7, sql-server-2008

Tenho um programa que vinha rodando no Ubuntu-server 17 há algum tempo. Este sistema realiza consultas em um servidor de banco de dados com MSSQL 2008.
Realizei a instalação do Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, e não alterei nada do código. Porém, não está mais funcionando a consulta.

Segue o código que estou utilizando:

**CÓDIGO DE CONEXÃO**

```
$serverName = "IP OF MY SERVER";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "DB NAME",
    "Uid" => "USER",
    "PWD" => "PASSWORD"
);
//Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
//Select Query
$tsql = "SELECT @@Version as SQL_VERSION";
//Executes the query
$getResults = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
//Error handling

if ($getResults == FALSE)
    die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));

sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);

function FormatErrors($errors) {
    /* Display errors. */
    echo "Errors: <br/>";
foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo "SQLSTATE: " . $error['SQLSTATE'] . "<br/>";
    echo "Code: " . $error['code'] . "<br/>";
    echo "Message: " . $error['message'] . "<br/>";
}
}
```

**CÓDIGO AJAX**: os valores de numero, item e sequência são informados em um formulário. Porém, já substituí por valores existentes no banco de dados para testar e o erro persistiu.

```
$.ajax({
                            url: 'producao/funcoes/consultaop.php',
                            async: false,
                            data: {
                                "numero": numero,
                                "item": item,
                                "sequencia": sequencia
                            },
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            cache: false,
                            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert("Erro na query "+errorThrown);
                            },
                            success: function (dados) {
                                p = dados.split(" - ");
                                produto = p[0];
                            }
                        });
```

**CÓDIGO DA QUERY**

```
include '../../bd/conexaomssql.php';

$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$sequencia = $_POST['sequencia'];

$consulta = "SELECT B1_DESC FROM SB1010 INNER JOIN SC2010 ON B1_COD = C2_PRODUTO WHERE C2_NUM+C2_ITEM+C2_SEQUEN = '$numero" . "$item" . "$sequencia'";

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $consulta);

if ($query == FALSE) {
    echo "Não encontrou!!";
}

$codproduto = "";
while ($linha = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $codproduto = $linha['B1_DESC'];
}
echo (json_encode($codproduto));
```

A versão atual do PHP é 7.2.5.

Lembrando que não houve alteração nenhuma no código depois da atualização do Ubuntu. Ele simplesmente não funcionou mais.

O que faço para voltar a funcionar?

Comment: Mas emite algum erro?

Comment: O erro que tem retornado é 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Isto é o seu computador local ou é um servidor de produção/site?

Comment: É um servidor local.

Comment: Vá no php.ini e habilite os erros em `display_errors=`, deixe ele assim: `display_erros=On`, então reinicie o Apache.

Comment: Fiz isto e o erro retornado agora é: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Diego deve ser algum erro de sintaxe ou você não instalou o `sqlsrv` no teu servidor. Cria um arquivo vazio chamado `phpinfo.php` e dentro dele cola isto `<?php phpinfo();`, ele deve estar na pasta do teu servidor, então chama pelo endereço `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`, vai carregar varios dados, procure por `error_log` e veja qual o local do log de erros, então quando achar abra esse arquivo e olhe os ultimos 10 erros nele, copie e cole na sua pergunta.

Comment: Guilherme, ambos local value e master value estão setados como no value.

Comment: Diego vá no phpinfo.php novamente e veja como esta display_erros e me avisa

Comment: display_errors = On <quebra de linha>
 Default Value: On <quebra de linha>
 Development Value: On <quebra de linha>
 Production Value: Off

Comment: Tem como enviar uma copia da página gerada pelo phpinfo.php?

Comment: Tem sim. Como você quer que eu envie?

Comment: Pode enviar via email, esta no meu perfil https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento?tab=profile

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado pelo suporte. Já enviei no seu e-mail.

Comment: Diego o display_errors aparece como off ainda, vá no arquivo `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` e procure a linha com `display_errors` mude para `display_errors=On`, então reinicia o servidor apache, se não der certo e continuar aparecendo erro 500 então reinicia o servidor inteiro

Comment: Guilherme eu estava mudando no local errado. Agora já configurei para On e no phpinfo() ele aparece como on. Agora ele está retornando o seguinte erro: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. Lembrando que estou pedindo para retornar o errorThrown por meio do ajax.

Comment: Diego esta parte sobre JSON esta estranha, não parece ter relação alguma com o seu código na pergunta, poderia colocar o código na integra por favor?

Comment: Caso queira mais algum código me avise por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na versão 17 não foi necessária a instalação do driver ssql.
No caso desta atualização para a 18.04, precisei instalá-lo e configurá-lo conforme este procedimento: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/

Segui a o procedimento após contribuição de [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento):

> "... deve ser algum erro de sintaxe ou você não instalou o sqlsrv no teu servidor..."